# How to pass a variable parameter value using the update_all() method in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the #update_all method to bulk update a huge amount of data at high speed in a rake task.
I have to update the email and phone fields.
For the phone field is easy to set to "00000000000".
In the email field i want to take the name stored in first_name field and add "@email.com".
I've been trying things like this:

```
User.update_all(email: "#{User.first_name}"+"@email.com", phone: "00000000000")
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
User.update_all("email = first_name || '@email.com', phone = '00000000000'")
```

`||` will concatenate strings. The first name of each user will be concatenated with the @email.com and assign to the email field.

Comment: It doesn't work. This is what i get in the rails console when i execute this line:
`User id: 3, first_name: "rick", second_name: "smith", email: "0", phone: "555-555-5555"`

Comment: But I could make it work using this:
 `User.update_all("email = first_name || '@email.com' ,phone = '00000000000'")`

Comment: This executes that string as part of the query, so it will only work if the database supports it. Assuming the database is postgres then it needs a `,` instead of the `AND`.

Comment: Ok, then I understand that if I use MySQL I should use AND instead of the comma, right?

Answer (score 2):

Another option, assuming you're using a database that supports the `CONCAT()` function (which most do):

```
User.update_all("email = CONCAT(first_name, '@email.com'), phone = '00000000000'")
```

Comment: This will work in MySQL, MariaDB, newer versions of MSSQL as well since they all support the `CONCAT()` function

Comment: @engineersmnky Good call. Updated the answer.